# Nginx try_files succeeds on deleted files, then nginx reports error with open()

Tags: nginx, docker, cache

I have this weird error that is happening where `try_files` directive successfully finds a file that was just deleted, then nginx proceeds to open the file and returns an error.

I am using a standard PHP backend setup with php-fpm. To reduce PHP work I am generating static HTML files which are then served by nginx directly. Everything is packed in docker containers, one for php and one for nginx.

Relevant part of `docker-compose` file:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "${WEB_PORT:-8100}:80"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

Nginx config file looks something like this:

```
server {
    ... ...
    set $bypass_url "/cache/${request_uri}/_index.html";

    location / {
        open_file_cache off;
        try_files $bypass_url $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

The idea is for `try_files` to first check if statically generated file exists if not, it shoul just pass everything to the upstream PHP.

When you visit `/` a static cache file will be generated in `/cache/_index.html`.

When you visit `/` next time, that generated file will be served. And this works as expected. The problem is with cache invalidation when cache file is deleted. Things get weird a little.

If cache was served at least once, then deleted, and then `/` was accessed right after deleting the cache, nginx will return the default 404 error page. If `/` is accessed once again, the request will be passed to upstream normally, something that should happen on the first request.

When 404 is returned, nginx will also log an error:

```
2023/09/28 14:34:32 [error] 22#22: *4 open() "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: server.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8100"
```

So, my question is, why is `try_files` not handling this? If I wait a minute after deleting the cache file and try to access that url the request will be passed to the upstream php and no 404 is returned. Which indicates that there is some sort of a timeout and after that things work as they should.

With `open_cache_file off` nginx is not caching open file descriptors. Could this be an issue with Docker and the way docker handles opened files? I tried running nginx in the debug mode, but I did not get any useful info. Just that try_files checked if missing file is present and apparently succeeded?

Nginx debug log:

```
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 try files handler
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 http script var: "/cache/_index.html"
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 trying to use file: "/cache/_index.html" "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html"
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 try file uri: "/cache/_index.html"
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 generic phase: 13
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 content phase: 14
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 content phase: 15
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 content phase: 16
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 content phase: 17
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 content phase: 18
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 content phase: 19
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 http filename: "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html"
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 add cleanup: 0000AAAAE8A4B440
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [error] 21#21: *11 open() "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: server.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8100"
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 http finalize request: 404, "/cache/_index.html?" a:1, c:1
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 http special response: 404, "/cache/_index.html?"
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 http set discard body
2023/09/28 14:02:17 [debug] 21#21: *11 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I am planning to try this outside docker, but this is weird behaviour and it seems like a bug with try_files or I missed some nginx configuration directive where I could disable this thing that looks like another cache layer.

Edit:
I did some more debugging and I ran a strace on nginx running inside the container.

This is the trace when try_files looks for _index.html, is unable to find it and then falls back to the upstream php.

```
[{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2234669808, u64=281472916413168}}], 512, 65000, NULL, 8) = 1
recvfrom(12, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:"..., 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1024
ioctl(12, FIONREAD, [439])              = 0
mmap(NULL, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffff853d8000
recvfrom(12, "|0|1366; _ym_isad=2; _cb=_OpSiCK"..., 7859, 0, NULL, NULL) = 439
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html", 0xffffe69f7170, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/www/html/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1760, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/www/html/index.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=405, ...}, 0) = 0
epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 12, {events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, data={u32=2234669808, u64=281472916413168}}) = 0
getsockname(12, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.19.0.5")}, [112 => 16]) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 13
... ...
```

It calls `newfstatat()` get's a no such file and then goes on. Now, this is the strace from when nginx fails with error and returns 404:

```
[{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2234669808, u64=281472916413168}}], 512, 65000, NULL, 8) = 1
recvfrom(12, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:"..., 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1024
ioctl(12, FIONREAD, [439])              = 0
mmap(NULL, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffff853d8000
recvfrom(12, "|0|1366; _ym_isad=2; _cb=_OpSiCK"..., 7859, 0, NULL, NULL) = 439
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/www/html/cache/_index.html", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
gettid()                                = 21
write(6, "2023/09/28 18:03:16 [error] 21#2"..., 236) = 236
... ...
```

The second time `newfstatat()` returns 0 as if file exists.

So, is it possible that nginx is still keeping the file descriptor or is this something that Docker is causing?

Last piece of information: if I connect to the container with `docker exec -it sh` and manually delete the file inside the container nginx will work as expected.

So this seems like a docker/container/hypervisor issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but when file is deleted on Linux opened handle remains valid. Is it possible, that NGINX process still sees the old, deleted file as valid but no other process may open it?

Although I do not find anything in documentation that would support my guess?

One hint might be note in fstat man page:

```
Note:  the order of fields in the stat structure varies somewhat across architectures.  In
       addition, the definition above does not show the padding bytes that may be present between
       some  fields  on  various  architectures.  Consult the glibc and kernel source code if you
       need to know the details.
```

Second is the question on StackOverflow where somebody is asking why NGINX keeps handles to deleted files:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249922/nginx-keeps-file-descriptors-open-for-deleted-files

Comment: I went and check this and nginx closes file after it is served.

I found out one more thing: if I connect to the container with docker exec and I delete file inside the container, this works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this is a docker related problem and it seems that there is a certain delay between a file deletion on the host, and when container registers that file is no longer there. This is probably due to sshfs.

Comment: This isn't really a good answer to your question; if you have a positive conclusion, that would be useful to post here;
suggest updating your question if you're still looking for a positive answer.